# Retrieve Dictionary From Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase

I'm trying to sort in different labels every items of a dictionary (in my exemple:vote in firebase go in the specify "votelabel", text in "textlabel" ... ), I tried to do it this way but I realy get stock. I think my problem is because every post have a new key and I don't Know How to go directly to the children

```
var posts: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()

@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
    let titre = Titre.text
    let soustitre = SousTitre.text
    let text = Text.text


    let newPosts: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "titre": titre!,
        "soustitre": soustitre!,
        "text": text!,
        "votes": votes
        ]



    ref.childByAppendingPath(current).childByAppendingPath("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(newPosts)
    ref.childByAppendingPath(current).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.value)
```

from here I realy get lost, I find this part on a tutorial, but to be honnest I didn't get it.

```
       var posts = [NSDictionary]()
        for item in snapshot.children{
            let child = item as! FDataSnapshot
            let dict = child.value as! NSDictionary
           posts.append(dict)
        }

        self.TextLabel.text = snapshot
    })

}
```

any clue will be very usefull !

thank you for your time !

[FireBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPwlI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your Firebase structure looks like this

```
posts
  node_0
    title: "some title"
    text: "some text"
    vote: "some vote"
  node_1
    title: "another title"
    text: "another text"
    vote: "another vote"
  node_2
    title: "yet another title"
    text: "yet another text"
    vote: "yet another vote"
```

and some code to read all of the posts nodes and display their children. The snapshot returns a set of key:value pairs so use the key to access the value

```
let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://jaytest.firebaseio.com")
let postsRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("posts"

postsRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock { snapshot in

  for child in snapshot.children {

    if let title = child.value["title"] as? String {
      print(title)
    }

    if let text = child.value["text"] as? String {
      print(text)
    }

    if let title = child.value["vote"] as? String {
      print(vote)
    }

  }
}
```

output is

```
some title
some text
some vote
another title
another text
another vote
yet another title
yet another text
yet another vote
```

based on a bit more info, the question is:

> How do I retrieve specific child data from a post in Firebase.

Suppose we have a tableview that lists our posts. Each post's key (node_0, node_1 & node_2) should be stored in an array that matches the tableView (it could be used as the datasource)

When the user clicks or taps a row, row #1 for example, look up the data in the array. In this case assume they tap row 1 in the tableView:

var theKey = myArray[1] //returns a key called 'node_1'

now that we have the key, getting the data from Firebase is a 'snap'

```
postsRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("posts")
thisPostRef = postsRef.childByAppendingPath(theKey)

thisPostRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value withBlock { snapshot in
  let title = snapshot.value["title"] //title = another title
  let text = snapshot.value["text"] // text = another text
  let vote = snapshot.value["vote"] //vote = another vote
}
```

Comment: Thank your this answer, I get to do this but I want to access just a specific node (that is changing according to the nodeID of the selected node) and in it node I want to be able retrive the diferent child. Is it possible to get a variable that will change the Key according to the selected post ? in order to make me able to retrieve the path or should I do it in an other way ?

Comment: @PierreDepingon I am not sure I understand the question fully. I think what you are asking is; if a user selects a post (in the ui) you want to retrieve that posts child data from Firebase?

Comment: sorry, yes it's exactly !

Comment: @PierreDepingon I added additional content to the answer. Hope it helps.